# How to handle exceptions with trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io, mobile-webkit, forge

I am using Trigger.io to with Catalyst for debugging. It appears that javascript exceptions thrown in the app do not bubble up to Trigger.io's Forge output messages.

I tried to alleviate this problem by using an on error handler like:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber){
  forge.logging.debug("JavaScript error: " + message + " on line " + linenumber + " for " + url);
};
```

This will indeed capture exceptions and output messages. However the `url`, and `linenumber` are never reported in this case. Making this minimally helpful.

Hoping there is some documented solution this this that I may have overlooked or someone has a more reliable solution.

## Update

here is a sample out put message:

`[FORGE] 'JavaScript error: TypeError: \'undefined\' is not an object on line 0 for undefined:0`

Using Jquery.

## Update 2

Seems that this only happens for TypeErrors of undefined. Other errors seem to be reporting

```
[FORGE] 'JavaScript error: SyntaxError: Parse error on line 21222 for http://localhost.com:3000/assets/mobile_manifest.js:21222'
[FORGE] 'app starting !'
[FORGE] 'JavaScript error: TypeError: \'undefined\' is not an object on line 0 for undefined:0'
```

Comment: Are url and linenumber both undefined or null or empty string?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or zepto?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try wrapping your code like this?

```
try {
  // Do something
} catch (err) {
  for (var e in err) {
    forge.logging.log(e + ":" + err[e]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have all my app code wrapped in a `try/catch` like this but instead of logging directly to forge it throws the exception. It should then get caught by the `window.onerror`. I'll experiment with this and see if its any more verbose.

Comment: changing the try/catch to this suggestion produces the same output just broken into different lines per the `forge.logging` for loop.